# How can I read a flag passed in when installing a npm package

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, pnpm

I am looking for a way to support optional dependencies installation. I manage a npm package and want to provide users with the option to include supported "plugins" but not include them in the main package installation code.

Imagine my package name is `my-package`, when others install it they run `pnpm install my-package`. I want to provide an option for them to run `pnpm install my-package --plugin my-plugin` and then based on that provided plugin install `my-plugin` dependency.

Obviously I will handle the check of whether the dependency has been installed or not in my code base.

I was looking at

- `optionalDependencies` but this is not the functionality I am looking for.
- `preinstall` script but since I am using `pnpm` this script runs after the dependencies have been installed. Also it does not seem to run when installing a package but only when installing the dependencies in a package.
- `pnpm hooks.readPackage` same as `preinstall`

Comment: Don't. Mark those as [peerDependency](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies), because plugins is _literally_ why that category exists =) And then let your users decide whether or not to install any of those, because _your package should not bypass the npm dependency management system_. That's just intentionally turning  your package into a security liability.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans sorry not sure why peerDependency solves it. My package will hold a module that uses my-plugin package/dependency. iiuc, peerDependency is to manage dependency version differences.

Comment: Yeah: don't. In your `pnpm install my-package --plugin my-plugin` example, make your users run `pnpm install my-package my-separately-published-plugin` and add `my-separately-published-plugin` as a `peerDependency` in the package file for `my-package`. Done. And then your package can check whether `my-separately-published-plugin` is available for use in its own code just fine (in CJS: try/catch the require, in ESM, use the dynamic import function) and if it's install, make use of it. Or even better (because that's what everyone else does) have a mypackage.config.js and load if it's mentioned.